# Laravel update query with cases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-update

I have situation wherein I want to update the boolean field i.e if it is 0 then update it with 1 and vice versa. I have written the mysql query, but I am having little trouble converting it to laravel supported format since I am new to laravel.

Following is my query:

```
update super_admins set status = CASE WHEN status = 0 then 1 else 0 end
where primary_key = 3;
```

A small lead on this would be a great help. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable

```
$status = true; //we assume status is true (1) at the begining;
SuperAdmin::where('id', 3)->update([
    'status' => !$status //becomes false (0)
]);
```

With query Builder

```
DB::table('super_admins')
->where('id', 3)
->update([
    'status' => !$status
]);
```

If the variable is unknown, you have some ways. Get it and toggle it.

```
$sadmin = SuperAdmin::find(3);
$sadmin->status = !$sadmin->status;
$sadmin->save();
```

Directly in the query

```
DB::update('update super_admins set status = !status where primary_key = ?', [3]);
```

Comment: Status is not known initially. @EddTheDove

Comment: You can check again

Comment: @EddyTheDove Any thoughts on how to write equivalent of `UPDATE TABLE TBL_NAME SET COL1 = CASE WHEN COL1 IS NULL THEN 'DEFAULT_VALUE' ELSE COL1` and this is for multiple rows of the table. Thus value may be not be determinable outside.